# Puppeteer wait for keyboard.type to finish typing long text

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer for scraping a website.

I only have simple problem with the following code:

```
await page.keyboard.type(data)
await page.click(buttonSelector)
```

The first line types really long text and I want the second line which is the submit button click to wait until typing is finished.

Comment: Maybe try [`page.waitForFunction()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args) before submitting. In the checking function you can compare if the current value of the input is equal to the needed data.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use:

```
await page.type(".your-selector", "your data", {delay: 10})
```

and set the required delay or as an alternative:

```
await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(".your-selector").value = "your data")
```

Comment: thank you for your answer
your alternative solution won't work with me, the website is a bit complicated cuz the element which i want to insert text into is <br/> which automatically switch to span when someone types on keyboard

Comment: @MostafaSobh Can you share a link to the page or concoct a simple reproducible example? How long is the text you're typing?

Comment: try to add "await page.waitForTimeout(3000)" between your "await page.keyboard.type(data)" and "await page.click(buttonSelector)"